# Redirecting unless client has come from paypal

Tags: html, paypal

I'm trying to have the HTML code check where a client came from so they can only access this page through a link and we will say this link is from Paypal after purchase and if they don't go through Paypal they will be redirected to the home page of my website, in this case, is home.com (not really).

My Code:

```
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://bypassdetected!'" />
header('location:../index.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to check if the contents of HTTP_REFERER includes 'paypal.com', although this is a dumb sort of check since it's easily spoofed and accomplishes little of value

Regarding the action your code then takes, you can't combine HTTP header location redirects with HTML redirects, it's one or the other, but if you do try to send both, the headers have to be set before any body content

Redirecting over to PayPal should be avoided in general. You should switch to a PayPal integration that does not use any redirects at all, such as this one: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client -- then, your site always stays loaded in the background, which is a far better modern web experience

Comment: No, I have a page PayPal redirects to where people can download my software and get a license key to my Software I don't want to just embed PayPal.

Comment: You should, and getting a license key should be handled with more sophisticated server-side logic than a redirect on success. Your design and implementation is poor

Comment: Here is the payment approval UI you could use: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server -- the two routes on your server it needs to call are 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ ... when you get a successful capture response then you can think about how to best provide the key to the customer in a retrievable way, maybe with both an email and display on a unique URL or only when logged in or something